# Есть два элемента "a", "b". В моем скрипте я получаю элемент "a", нужно получить "b", который есть дочерним

Tags: html, css

Есть два элемента "a", "b". В моем скрипте я получаю элемент "a", нужно получить "b", который есть дочерним.

```
<style>
    #a #b {
        background:blue;
    }
    </style>

<script>
var x = document.getElementById("a");
</script>
```

Comment: с jQuery: `x.find('#b');`. Если b - ребенок, то `x.children('#b');`

Answer (score 1):

`x.children` - массив всех дочерних элементов.